# Find the nth cross-alternate sum

Tags: code-golf, sequence

Given an input of a single positive integer, output the "cross-alternate sum"
that corresponds to that integer.

Take the example of the input `n=5`. To find the cross-alternate sum, first
create a square grid of width and height `n` that, reading from left to right
and top to bottom, starts at `1` and increases by one each position:

```
 1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```

Then, take the sums from the grid that form a "cross" (that is, both diagonals
combined):

```
 1           5
    7     9
      13
   17    19
21          25

1 5 7 9 13 17 19 21 25
```

Finally, take the alternating sum of this sequence:

```
1+5-7+9-13+17-19+21-25

-11
```

Another example, for `n=6` (just to show what the cross looks like for
even-numbered `n`):

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6
 7  8  9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35 36

 1              6
    8       11
      15 16
      21 22
   26       29
31             36

1+6-8+11-15+16-21+22-26+29-31+36

20
```

Since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code in bytes will win.

Here are the correct outputs for `n=1` to `n=100`, which you can use as test
cases:

```
1
4
-3
10
-11
20
-23
34
-39
52
-59
74
-83
100
-111
130
-143
164
-179
202
-219
244
-263
290
-311
340
-363
394
-419
452
-479
514
-543
580
-611
650
-683
724
-759
802
-839
884
-923
970
-1011
1060
-1103
1154
-1199
1252
-1299
1354
-1403
1460
-1511
1570
-1623
1684
-1739
1802
-1859
1924
-1983
2050
-2111
2180
-2243
2314
-2379
2452
-2519
2594
-2663
2740
-2811
2890
-2963
3044
-3119
3202
-3279
3364
-3443
3530
-3611
3700
-3783
3874
-3959
4052
-4139
4234
-4323
4420
-4511
4610
-4703
4804
-4899
5002
```

Comment: Nit pick: That's not an alternating sum. You're adding the first two terms.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Jelly, <s>21</s> <s>19</s> <s>11</s> <s>10</s> 7 bytes

```
²~³¡H+2
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=wrJ-wrPCoUgrMg&input=&args=NQ)

### Idea

Assume for a second that the first term of the final sum is subtracted rather than added.

Let **n** be a positive integer.

#### Even case

```
 1              6
    8       11
      15 16
      21 22
   26       29
31             36
```

The differences between the diagonal elements on the lower half of the rows are the first **n ÷ 2** odd natural numbers. Since **1 + 3 + 5 + … + (2k + 1) = k<sup>2</sup>**, they sum to **(n ÷ 2)<sup>2</sup> = n<sup>2</sup> ÷ 4**.

In this example

```
- 1 + 6 - 8 + 11 - 15 + 16 - 21 + 22 - 26 + 29 - 31 + 36  =
-(1 - 6)-(8 - 11)-(15 - 16)-(21 - 22)-(26 - 29)-(31 - 36) =
(    5   +   3    +    1  )+(   1    +    3    +    5   ) =
             9             +              9               = 18
```

Thus, the sum is **2 × n<sup>2</sup> ÷ 4 = n<sup>2</sup> ÷ 2**.

#### Odd case

```
 1           5
    7     9
      13
   17    19
21          25
```

The differences between the diagonal elements on the corresponding rows from above and below (`1` and `5`, and `21` and `25`; `7` and `9`, and `17` and `19`) is the same, so they will cancel out in the alternating sum.

In this example

```
- 1 + 5 - 7 + 9 - 13 + 17 - 19 + 21 - 25  =
-(1 - 5)-(7 - 9)- 13 +(17 - 19)+(21 - 25) =
    4   +   2   - 13 -    2    -    4     = -13
```

All that's left is the negative of the central element, which is the arithmetic mean of the first and last number, so it can be calculated as **-(n<sup>2</sup> + 1) ÷ 2**.

#### General case

Since **~x = -(x + 1)** for two's complement integers (**~** denotes bitwise NOT), the formula for the odd case can be rewritten as **~n<sup>2</sup> ÷ 2**.

Also, since the first term (**1**) of the original sum is added instead of subtracted, the above formulas leave an error of **2**, which has to be corrected.

Therefore, the n<sup>th</sup> cross-alternate sum is **n<sup>2</sup> ÷ 2 + 2** if **n** is even, and **~n<sup>2</sup> ÷ 2 + 2** if it is odd.

Finally, bitwise NOT is an involution, i.e., **~~x = x** for all **x**. This way **~~~x = ~x**, **~~~~x = x**, and, in general, **~<sup>n</sup>x** (meaning that **~** is applied **n** times) is **x** if **n** is even and **~x** if it is odd.

Thus, we can rewrite our general formula as **~<sup>n</sup>n<sup>2</sup> ÷ 2 + 2** for all positive integers **n**.

### Code

```
²~³¡H+2    Main link. Input: n

²          Yield n².
 ~         Apply bitwise NOT to n²...
  ³¡           n times.
    H      Halve the result.
     +2    Add 2.
```

Comment: I knew there was some sort of simple formula, but your explanation and execution is just amazing. +1

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, <s>40</s> <s>38</s> 22 bytes

Using that new-fangled, fancy closed form solution that's all the rage!

```
n=>(n%2?3-n*n:4+n*n)/2
```

Thanks to ThomasKwa, I can eliminate my costly recursive function.

Comment: You just need to bitwise NOT once if n%2. Actually, I think in JS it might be shorter to just do `(n%2?3-n*n:4+n*n)/2`

Answer (score 4):

## Jelly, 12 bytes

```
RṖµ²+‘×-*$SC
```

Try it [here](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UuG5lsK1wrIr4oCYw5ctKiRTQw&input=&args=MTAw).

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 13 <s>15</s> bytes

```
ri2#_{~}*2/2+
```

Two bytes off thanks to Dennis.

[**Try it online!**](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cmkyI197fn0qMi8yKw&input=NQ)

Comment: My first CJam answer!

Comment: Replacing `2%{~}&` with `{~}*` saves two bytes.

Comment: @Dennis Very good! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### [Minkolang 0.15](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), <s>26</s> <s>15</s> 13 bytes

Using Dennis' insane algorithm, and golfed off another two bytes thanks to him. That guy is responsible for halving of byte count!

```
n2;d[~]4+2:N.
```

[Try it here!](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=n2%3Bd%5B%7E%5D4%2B2%3AN%2E&input=99)

#### Explanation

> @VoteToClose `n`^2, apply bitwise NOT `n` times, add four, halve. – [Thomas Kwa](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39328/thomas-kwa) [7 mins ago](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71242/find-the-nth-cross-alternate-sum#comment174457_71247)

See [Dennis' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71247/12914) for the explanation of why that works. In a comment on this answer, he suggested another improvement that works because `:` is integer division, so I can negate the top of stack and not worry about the +1 from doing the binary complement. Furthermore, n and n^2 have the same parity, which removes the need for a swap.

```
n                Take number from input - n
 2;              n**2
   d             Duplicates top of stack
    [~]          For loop that negates the top of stack n times
       4+        Add 4
         2:      Divide by 2
           N.    Output as number and stop.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pure Bash, 28

Well now that @Dennis has showed us all how to do this, this needs updating:

```
echo $[-1**$1*($1*$1+1)/2+2]
```

---

Previous answer:

## Bash + GNU utilities, 77

Here's a start:

```
a=$1
(seq 1 $[a+1] $[a*a]
seq $1 $[a>1?a-1:1] $[a*a])|sort -un|paste -sd+-|bc
```

N is passed as a command-line parameter.

`paste` is really handy here for producing the alternating sum.  The `-d` option allows a list of separator characters, which are used cyclically.

Comment: `$[-1**$1*$1*$1+4>>1]` is even shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, <s>41</s> <s>40</s> <s>25</s> <s>19</s> 16 bytes

```
n->-n%2$n^2÷2+2
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts an integer and returns an integer. To call it, assign it to a variable.

The approach here, devised by Dennis, is as follows. First we get the parity of *n*, i.e. *n* (mod 2), and negate it. This gives us 0 for even inputs and -1 for odd. We then bitwise XOR with *n*<sup>2</sup>. When *n* is even, this is just *n*<sup>2</sup> because XOR with 0 is just the number. When *n* is odd, XOR with -1 is the same as bitwise negation. So at this point we either have *n*<sup>2</sup> or the bitwise NOT of *n*<sup>2</sup>. We integer divide this by 2 and add 2 to get the result.

Saved a byte thanks to Sp3000 on a previous version, and saved 9 thanks to Dennis on this one!

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 13 <s>27</s> bytes

Using Dennis' amazing formulas:

```
2^t2\?Q_]2/2+
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=Ml50Mlw_UV9dMi8yKw&input=NQ)

Direct approach (**27 bytes**):

```
2^:GtetXdwPXdhutn:-1w^!*s2+
```

Answer (score 2):

## GolfScript, 12 bytes

```
~2?.{~}*2/2+
```

This uses the algorithm from [my Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71247). [Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=fjI_Lnt-fSoyLzIr&input=NQ)

#### How it works

```
~            # Evaluate the input.
 2?          # Square it.
   .         # Push a copy of the square.
    {~}      # Push a code block that applies bitwise NOT.
       *     # Execute it n² times. Since n² and n have the same parity,
             # this is equivalent to executing in only n times.
        2/   # Halve the result.
          2+ # Add 2.
```

Answer (score 2):

### ES7, 17 bytes

```
n=>-1**n*n*n+4>>1
```

Simple port of @Dennis's Python 2 answer.

While writing this answer I managed to golf my ES6 port to 17 bytes too!

```
n=>(n*n^-n%2)/2+2
```

Answer (score 1):

## Jolf, 13 bytes

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=wr0_bc-Bai0zUWorNFFq)

```
½?mρj-3Qj+4Qj
 ?mρj         if parity of j
     -3Qj     return 3 - j*j
         +4Qj else return 4 + j*j
½             (and halve the result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 24 bytes

```
lambda n:(-1)**n*n*n/2+2
```

This uses the algorithm from [my Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71260), with a minor modification:

Instead of applying `~` **n** times, we apply `-` **n** times (by multiplying by **(-1)<sup>n</sup>**). This is equivalent because **~x = -x - 1** and integer division floors in Python, so **~x / 2 = (-x - 1) / 2 = -x / 2**.

Answer (score 1):

## GS2, 9 bytes

```
V,@!α2+''
```

This uses the algorithm from [my Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71247). [Try it online!](http://gs2.tryitonline.net/#code=VixAIc6xMisnJw&input=NQ)

```
V,@e 7+''
```

is equally short, but notably contains no non-ASCII characters.

#### How it works

```
V          Parse the input as an integer n.
 ,         Compute n².
  @        Push a copy of n².
   !       Bitwise NOT.
    α      Make a block of the previous instruction.
     2     Execute the block n² times. Since n² and n have the same parity,
           this is equivalent to executing in only n times.
      +    Halve the result.
       ''  Increment twice.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
+2/u_GQ*QQ2
```

Try it online in the [Pyth Compiler](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B2%2Fu_GQ%2aQQ2&input=5&debug=0).

#### How it works

This uses the algorithm from [my Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71247), with a minor modification:

Instead of applying `~` **n** times, we apply `-` **n** times (by multiplying by **(-1)<sup>n</sup>**). This is equivalent because **~x = -x - 1** and integer division floors in Pyth, so **~x / 2 = (-x - 1) / 2 = -x / 2**.

```
+2/u_GQ*QQ2  Evaluated input: Q

       *QQ   Yield Q².
   u  Q      Set G = Q². For each non-negative integer below Q:
    _G         Set G = -G.
             Return G.
  /       2  Halve the result.
+2           Add 2.
```

Answer (score 1):

## dc, 17

Using the same tried and tested formula from Dennis:

```
?dd*1+r_1r^*2/2+p
```

<strike>Try it online</strike> <sub>Oh, why doesn't the Ideone bash sandbox include `dc`?</sub>

#### Command-line Test:

```bash
for i in {1..100}; do echo $i | dc -e '?dd*1+r_1r^*2/2+p'; done
```

Comment: `?2^1+2~2*1-*2+p` saves two bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## J, 16 bytes

```
[:<.2%~4+*:*_1^]
```

This uses the same algorithm as my Jelly answer. Test it with [J.js](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=(%5B%3A%3C.2%25~4%2B*%3A*_1%5E%5D)%2010%2011).

Answer (score 0):

## Dyalog APL, 13 bytes

```
⌊2+.5××⍨×¯1*⊢
```

This uses the same algorithm as my Jelly answer. Test it on [TryAPL](http://tryapl.org/?a=%28%u230A2+.5%D7%D7%u2368%D7%AF1*%u22A2%29%2010%2011&run).

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 33 bytes ([Try it online](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo))

```
i=(...)print((-1)^i*i*i/2-.5*i%2)
```

How it works:

```
i=(...)print((-1)^i*i*i/2-.5*i%2)
i=(...)                           Take input and store to i
       print(
             (-1)^i               Raise (-1) to the i-th power: -1 if odd, 1 if even
                   *i*i/2         Multiply by i squared and halved.
                         -.5*i%2  i%2 is the remainder when i is divided by 2
                                  if i is odd, then i%2 will be 1, and this expression
                                  will evaluate to -0.5
                                  but if i is even, then i%2 will be 0, which makes
                                  this expression evaluate to 0
                                )
```